# Set label font color from hex value

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to set a font color on a QLabel to a hex value received from the server.

Currently I am just setting the text of the label but have no idea how to set the font color.

```
def set_stat_lbl(self):
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Foreground, self.stat_value_color)
    self.stat_lbl.setText(_translate("rep_stat", self.stat_name, None))
    self.stat_lbl.setPalette(palette)
```

Where `self.stat_value_color` would be a hex string like `#fb0000`. The above code clearly doesn't work as it wants a color not a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also instantiate a `QColor` with the hex string.

```
palette = self.stat_lbl.palette()
color = QColor('#112233')
palette.setColor(QPalette.Foreground, color)
self.stat_lbl.setPalette(palette)
```

Also, you can use css directly on the widget, as opposed to having to construct it each time when setting the text:

```
self.stat_lbl.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: #112233;}')
self.stat_lbl.setText('This is colored text')
```

Comment: I think I like your second option the best and will probably go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using CSS.

```
def set_stat_lbl(self):
    value = "<font color='{}'>{}</font>".format(self.stat_value_color, self.stat_name)
    self.stat_lbl.setText(_translate("rep_stat", value, None))
```